# Using "Let's Encrypt" TLS with a Google Load Balancer? (Kubernetes/GKE)

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, google-kubernetes-engine, go

I've been trying to test out Kubernetes on Google Cloud, but would need HTTPS/TLS (only) exposed on the deployed application. To start, I just followed this tutorial, which worked fine for plain HTTP over port 80: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart

To get TLS support working with **[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)**, I've tried (without success):

- Ended up with "CIPHER MISMATCH" errors when serving via the Golang
  application itself (then just doing a generic TCP load balancer for the node cluster) ...
  https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert
- This method didn't work either: https://github.com/ahmetb/gke-letsencrypt

... Does anyone have any suggestions on how to serve just HTTPS for the original tutorial? No need for plain HTTP unless it's a freebie, but I'm really scratching my head on this one since I haven't worked with Kubernetes before and I haven't been able to get Let's Encrypt working at all here.

Comment: have you considered using a tiny VM as a load balancer running Traefik? It supports Let's Encrypt renewal without any effort and costs a little less than Google's load balancer. A lot of good info here: https://estl.tech/configuring-https-to-a-web-service-on-google-kubernetes-engine-2d71849520d

Comment: @sippybear Nice article! One issue with using a VM is that it’s linked to the cluster’s ephemeral IP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, it turns out that you can just add TLS directly on the load balancer now, and it'll issue a Let's Encrypt certificate automatically. This is doable via Cloud Console:

[image: Let's Encrypt issued on GCP LB]

No clue why this isn't more well-known.

Comment: Nice, probably newly added functionality.  You should accept your answer so people know you've found a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#creating_an_ingress_with_a_managed_certificate) to create a Kubernetes Ingress with a Google managed certificate. At a high level, this involves two stpes:

1. Create a ManagedCertificate resource (this is a beta feature in GKE)
2. Use the `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates` annotation in your Ingress manifest to point to the managed certificate created in step 1

Google will automatically create a certificate for you using one of two CAs. If you're adamant on using Let's Encrypt, you can add a [CAA record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization#Record) to your DNS zone as follows:

`your_domain. CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"`

Alternatively, if your app is already up and running in GKE and sitting behind an existing Global HTTP Load Balancer, you can follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#create-managed-ssl-cert-resource) to add a Google managed certificate to your load balancer. The end result is essentially the same regardless of which method you use.